# Remove items from a collection if one date is greater than another

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to use linq to remove items from a collection where one date is greater than another. I know I need to use [`DateTime.Compare()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm a bit unsure how to go about it.

If this were allowed, my code would look like the following:

```
ciLibrary.RemoveAll(x => x.LastSyncToWebsite >= x.Modified);
```

Since this doesn't work with `DATETIME` values how do I properly represent this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` values can be compared using `>=`. What you need is a `Where`:

```
clLibrary.Where(x => !(x.LastSyncToWebsite >= x.Modified))
```

or equivalently:

```
clLibrary.Where(x => x.LastSyncToWebsite < x.Modified)
```

This generates a new IEnumerable, leaving `clLibrary` unchanged. If `clLibrary` is of type `List<T>`, you can:

```
clLibrary = clLibrary.Where(x => x.LastSyncToWebsite < x.Modified).ToList();
```

If `clLibrary` is of type `T[]`, you can:

```
clLibrary = clLibrary.Where(x => x.LastSyncToWebsite < x.Modified).ToArray();
```

Comment: Actually if `clLibrary` is `List<T>` your original statement should work, too, but it would not be LINQ because `RemoveAll` belongs to `List<T>`, not LINQ.

Comment: You're right on the second point - I actually found that I was pulling the date through in another area of the system. I'd looked at it so many times I was starting to be convinced it was my date comparison, not my dates. thanks for this post - gave me confidence to dig a little deeper and ended up solving the real problem!